# Display popup on disabled link in ADF

Tags: popup, oracle-adf

I need to display popup on disabled link click in ADF. As soon as I click on disabled link or button. Popup should be displayed. I tried with Action and ActionListner. But it will work, if button or link is enabled.

I can give shortDesc property to hover the text. But I am searching a way for getting a popup on click.

I surfed so many places. But I could not find it. Please suggest me some input on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add another link and add a css to make it like a disabled link.
Or on the show popupbehaviour make the triger type = hover